# PHP MYSQL Eliminate Comma from Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode, implode

tb1

```
-----------------
id | codetb1
-----------------
1  | code1,code2
2  | code2,code3
```

---

tb2

```
-----------------
codetb2 | cost
-----------------
code1   | $20
code2   | $40
code3   | $60
```

---

save.php -> This is how I insert checkbox values to the database.

```
$codetb1 = $_POST['codetb1'];
var_dump($codetb1);

// Setting up a blank variable to be used in the coming loop.
$allStyles = "";
// For every checkbox value sent to the form.
foreach ($typeocodetb1fvisit as $style) {
    // Append the string with the current array element,
    // and then add a comma and a space at the end.
    $allStyles .= $style . ", ";
}
// Delete the last two characters from the string.
$allStyles = subs

tr($allStyles, 0, -2);
```

---

Result.php -> this is my connection and how I can get my result

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tb1, tb2 WHERE
  tb1.codetbl1 = tb2.codetbl2 AND
  tb1.id='$id'";
```

---

Hi all -- your help is greatly appreciated. I have 2 databases (table 1 and table 2). I would like to have the 2 databases linked with one another. I am having trouble accomplishing this. For example,  I tried explode but I couldnt make it work.

So How can I get rid of that comma from codetb1 and find a way to match with codetb2. So finally I can get cost. Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to reformulate your question so others do not need to read such unclear sentences. Do your best - getting proper help from others may depend on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Normalized Schema

In my opinion, the only "real" answer to this question is to model the domain with a normalized schema. Specifically, we should never have one column storing more than exactly one piece of data. The term we use to describe your domain is that there is a **many-to-many relationship**, where one row in tb1 is related to many rows in tb2, and one row in tb2 can be related to many rows in tb1. The destination schema will look like this:

tb1

```
---------
id | ...
---------
1  | ...
2  | ...
```

---

tb2

```
----------
id | cost
----------
 1 | $20
 2 | $40
 3 | $60
```

---

tb1_tb2

```
-----------------
 tb1_id | tb2_id 
-----------------
    1   |    1
    1   |    2
    2   |    2
    2   |    3
```

Then, the way you select them depends on what you want. Here are some examples:

The highest and lowest "cost" for each row in tbl1:

```
SELECT tb1.name, MIN(tb2.cost) as low, MAX(tb2.cost) as high
FROM tb1 
  JOIN tb1_tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.tb1_id
  JOIN tb2_ON tb1_tb2.tb2_id = tb21.id
GROUP BY tb1.name
```

The sum of costs for rows in tb1:

```
SELECT tb1.name, SUM(tb2.cost) as total
FROM tb1 
  JOIN tb1_tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.tb1_id
  JOIN tb2_ON tb1_tb2.tb2_id = tb21.id
GROUP BY tb1.name
```

The idea is to model each "thing" completely and distinctly; and the trick is to think of each relationship between a tb1 and a tb2 as a distinct "thing" (i.e. each one has a single row in tb1_tb2; the relationship is a full-class citizen in a normalized schema)

Inserting is fairly straightforward once you think about the relationship as a distinct entity. If you have a tb1 and a tb2 you want to relate, simply add a tow to tb1_tb2 with their ids.

Answer (score 2):

First, the answer which does not involve changing your schema:

MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb1, tb2 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tb2.codetb2, tb1.codetb1);
```

However, the ideal solution is to normalize the schema (time permitting I will submit another answer with more details)

Comment: unfortunately, it didnt work. Thanks for your time. Actually my database is more complicated than what I tried to explain. All my tables are connected to each other. This is the last step, I am trying to fix. Multiply list, I am getting from the database. All those selected list items, I am inserting with implode ( commas ) then last step of this application. these items. I am trying to get rid of those commas and get list of what prices according to each items and thats it. Do you have any suggestion that I can find solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I have a suggestion; see my other answer (normalize the schema). Also, it's possible that you need to remove spaces, as it likely mucks up the ability of find_in_set to work with your strings. I know normalization can seem complex, but there are myriad reasons we do it; what you have is one concrete example. This is really sloppy stuff, and it will be nasty to maintain in the long run. Take pride in what you build, build it right.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM tb1, tb2 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tb2.codetb2, tb1.codetb1);

Comment: Actually it worked! Thanks but, I am getting the result for first value. How can I get the result for next value after comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> ```
> $query="SELECT * FROM tb1, tb2 WHERE
> `tb1.codetbl1` LIKE concat('%', concat(`tb2.codetbl2`, '%')) AND
> tb1.id='$id'";
> ```

Edit: this would cause a bit of problems if the codes could get more than one-digit numbers (like code10, code11). You should not strip the last comma, and use:

> ```
> $query="SELECT * FROM tb1, tb2 WHERE
> `tb1.codetbl1` LIKE concat('%', concat(`tb2.codetbl2`, ',%')) AND
> tb1.id='$id'";
> ```

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. Maybe I couldnt make it work. Thanks for your time. Maybe I shouldnt insert anything with commas into database

Answer (score 0):

table2 could have a column table_id and your query will then be

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tb1, tb2 WHERE
tb1.codetbl1 = tb2.tb1_id AND
tb1.id='$id'";
```

from your question i figure its like a cart you are trying to build so you should have tables like these.

```
//table customer_cart
 -------------------------
 | id|item_code|customerid|
 -------------------------
 |1  |itemcode1|1         |
 --------------------------
 |2  |itemcode2|1         |
 --------------------------
```

and then item table

```
 ---------------
 | id|price    |
 ---------------
 |1  |$30      |
 ---------------
 |2  |$60      |
 ---------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But its not easy for me to change entire database table structure. I have more than 6 tables. All connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables using `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT a.id, b.cost
FROM   tb1 a
JOIN   tb2 b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.code, a.codetb1) > 0
```

Comment: I didnt quite understand that structure. a and b? I tried it with my understanding and result is empty screen.